# How is ANADEW pronounced?

Tags: terminology, conlang-community

How is the acronym [ANADEW](https://conlang.stackexchange.com/questions/790/what-is-the-meaning-of-anadew) pronounced among conlang enthusiasts. I have seen it only in print so far and I want to know whether the letters are spelled out or whether it is pronounced as if it were an English word.

Comment: Well, spelling out each letter makes 8 syllables, so I guess it's safe to assume it is pronounced as an English word.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As a native speaker of American English from the middle of the North American continent, I have always pronounced it as /ˈænədu/, like Xanadu (the movie), but with out the leading /z/. Visit https://tophonetics.com for a close approximation (capitalization ignored, British and American options generate the same audio).

Comment: In some dialects, of both US and UK English *dew* rhymes with *do* but in others it is /dju/. We can assume *ANADEW* rhymes with *dew* so if you say /dju/ then say /ˈænədju/.

Comment: I concur with lee.